# Is it possible to use the webHID API over and RDP connection?

Tags: google-chrome, rdp, webhid

We recently implemented the webHID API for one of our sites (it is such a godsend) and have the client asking if they can use the devices over a Microsoft RDP connection?
I imagine this would depend on the RDP client and whether they can/do send HID events over the RDP connection.
From some initial research it looks like you can redirect USB over RDP but don't think this will work for us as I couldn't get my device mapping done with the webUSB API.
If anyone has any input on this it would be greatly appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

[WebUSB](http://web.dev/usb), [WebHID](http://web.dev/hid) and [Web Serial](http://web.dev/serial) should work with a remoted USB device.

That said, there may be bugs if these devices don't appear to applications like Chrome in quite the same way they do when connected locally. If they don't, it would be interesting to get logs from `chrome://device-log` and see how the device appears in the Windows Device Manager.

Please file a bug at https://crbug.com/new and let us know so that we can keep track of this issue.

Comment: Hi, I did some testing yesterday and wasn't able to get the local devices to be recognized on the remote server.
I tried enabling all of the Local Resources for the RDP connection but no luck. I checked the remote Device Manager and don't see the devices listed in there at all. When using it locally, the devices do appear in the Device Manager.
I will work on getting those logs and submit a new bug shortly.